# Similar problem to Subset Sum?

Tags: np-complete, partitions, subset-sum

I've been trying to search for a problem which I think could be similar to Subset Sum.
The definition of the problem would be as follows:

Given k $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ and S = {$s_1$,...,$s_n$} s.t. $s_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, how many subsets $S' \subseteq S$ exist s.t. $\sum S' \geq k$.

I don't know if this problem has been studied previously, but I can't find anything. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not in NP because it is not a decision problem. Instead it would lie in #P because you want it to output the number of accepting paths of a non-deterministic machine.

You can look for some #P problems but I don't think each NP problem has a studied equivalent there.

If you changed it into a decision problem of: 'Is there more (or less) than $l$ subsets with $\Sigma_{s\in S'}s \ge k$ then this would be a decision problem but since $l$ is bounded by $2^n$ this is still not in NP. It is surely in PSPACE, but I can't put it anywhere lower in the polynomial hierarchy right now.

Comment: Since it's $\geq k$ and not $=k$, it might actually be polytime, no?

Comment: I don't think it's polytime even with that. I just found that there exists a generalization of this problem called [Littlewood-Offord problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%E2%80%93Offord_problem)

Comment: It's true I didn't realize the inequlity might be actually a much simpler problem. The Littlewood-Offord lemma binds only the solution, not the runtime as far as I can tell.